# Обновление таблицы в реальном времени из бд

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Есть Бд, есть компоненты на форме
FDTable, DBGrid, DataSource
Вопрос, как обновить таблицу DBGrid, в режиме реального времени
Ибо если я в неё добавил, она обновляется, только по перезаходе в программу
В каком компоненте, нужно обновить?
БД mssql, Rad Studio c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все спасибо, я решил
FDTable->Refresh();